# Very simple Haskell code doesn't work, "Variable not in scope"

Tags: variables, haskell, scope

I'm new to Haskell and doing some simple exercises. For this exercise I'm writing a function that checks whether one list is a subset of another list using recursion.

Here's the code:

```
subset [] xs = True

subset (x:xs) ys = if elem x ys == False then False
                   else subset (tail xs) (delete x ys)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
C:\Functioneel programmeren\week4.hs:9:43: error:
    Variable not in scope: delete :: t1 -> t t1 -> t t1
```

What does this even mean?

This program only works when I change "(delete x ys)" to "ys", but then it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `delete` defined?

Comment: I was under the impression that that was a built-in function in Haskell: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete

Comment: By the way, your `if` can be rewritten in a more readable form as `elem x ys && subset ...`. Usually, we tend to avoid `==False` and `if..then False` in Haskell. Also `tail xs` looks wrong, are you sure you don't want `xs` instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` needs to be imported. According to https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=delete, you should add `import Data.List` to the beginning.

Besides, I guess your function `subset` is wrong. The result of `subset [1, 2, 1] [1, 2, 3]` is `False`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had to import it. I think the result of that should be false though, since there is only a single 1 in the second list in your example

Comment: I don't know what should `subset` do, so I just guess it. I guessed wrong.

Comment: @Meurth A  set can, mathematically speaking, not contain duplicates. In that case, `sublist` would probably the better name for your function, since lists/sequences can contain duplicates. from a mathematical point of view, {1, 1, 1} equals {1, 1} equals {1}.

Comment: @Polygnome Thanks for the reply, I suppose my teacher could learn something from that! :D